# Unable to install Swirl Courses in RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, github, swirl

I'm trying to install Swirl courses in RStudio on 64-bit Ubuntu 15.10, and I am running across an error. I tried to install a course using the command `install_from_swirl("Data_Analysis")`, but the system either just hangs (R needs to be interrupted to recover from this), or I get the following error:

```
Error in unzip(path, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file '/home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/swirl/Courses
 /temp.zip' cannot be opened
```

The `temp.zip` doesn't appear to be a zip archive (I'm unable to open in on the command line).

Comment: You can try installing course manually. Instructions are available on [swirl github repo](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl_courses).

Answer (score 1):

You actually helped me with the command! I used

```
    install_course("Data Analysis")
```

but it didn't work, then I used

```
    install_from_swirl("Data_Analysis")
```

and it worked! Try running the swirl library first:

```
    library("swirl")
    install_from_swirl("Data_Analysis")    # CASE SENSITIVE!
    swirl()
```

I wish you luck!